# Icons in Android O

Tags: android, icons, material-design, android-launcher, android-8.0-oreo

Running my projects in Android O device made my launcher icons fit inside a rounded background.

All my icons are squared, following the Material Design rules, and I wanna to keep this way for older Android versions. But I also want to endure Android O design rule, filling all that ugly white space, as in the Maps launcher icon, as shown in the image.

[image: Android O icons]

There is any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Android O introduces adaptive launcher icons, which can display a
>   variety of shapes across different device models

For more refer [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/adaptive-icons.html)

```
<adaptive-icon>
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

Comment: I don't wanna to import my project to Android Studio 3.0 just to make the adaptive icons. There is any online tool to make those icons?

Comment: You can create one dummy project and you can create an icon in that. You don't need to import yours project completely. As of now there no online tool to generate adaptive icon

Answer (score 1):

You can set both [`android:icon` `android:roundIcon` on your manifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#circular-icons). If you are running on android 7.1+, the launcher will choose the rounded one if the device supports it.

Starting on Android O, we have the [adaptive icon concept](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/adaptive-icons.html). You should create the resources for `android:icon` and `android:roundIcon` using `<adaptive-icon>`:

```
<adaptive-icon>
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

Comment: Should the `mimap-anydpi-v26` folder only contain `ic_launcher.xml`? No `ic_launcher_round.xml`?